# Swift Pong(No SpriteKit): Detect side of paddle that the ball hit

Tags: swift, collision-detection, pong

Currently, I am making a pong game in Swift(without SpriteKit) that is one player: the ball can bounce off all sides of the view. After some research, I used this algorithm to detect collisions:

```
if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
    rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
    rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
    rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y) {
        // collision detected!
}
```

This works fine, but how can I detect which side of the paddle that the ball hit?

I need to know this because: if the ball hits the bottom or top side of the paddle, I would multiply the y increment by -1. If the ball hits the left or right side of the paddle, I would multiply the x increment by -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decent(but not very good) solution. This function returns `true` if the ball touches either the left or the right side of the paddle, and `false` if the ball touches either the top or bottom of the paddle.

```
func touchHorizontalPaddle() -> Bool {
    if abs(ball.origin.x + ball.width - paddle.origin.x) < 1 || 
       abs(ball.origin.x - (paddle.origin.x + paddle.width)) < 1 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

The main issue with this function is that the "less than 1" part is hardcoded. Thus, if the ball speed is too fast, or the increment is too large, the conditional statement may get messed up. Overall, though, it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If rect1 and rect2 are both CGRect then you can get the mid point with...

```
rect1.midY
```

And

```
rect2.midY
```

You can then find if the mid point ball (whichever one it is) is higher or lower than the midpoint of the paddle.

```
if rect1.midY >= rect2.midY
```

Etc...

On a side note, you’d be much better off using SpriteKit for this. But if you’re just doing it for fun then carry on. Hope it works out. :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. If I use `if rect1.midY >= rect2.midY`, couldn't the ball be touching the left or right sides of the paddle?

Comment: You only mentioned that you want to detect top or bottom? If you want to detect left and right you can use midX instead. Oh just read the last part of your question. Yeah, you can use midX also and the logic would be the same

Comment: In my case, the ball can hit *any* side of the paddle. What should I do?

Comment: Then check the midY to update the y speed. And then check the midX to update the x. Unless I’m mistaken with what you’re saying. Pong is a very well defined game. If the ball is behind the paddle it doesn’t bounce back. So it’s only going to hit from one side.

Comment: If you’re doing something different then I suggest adding pictures to help explain.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear: basically, my game is kind of a one player Pong game. The ball can bounce of walls and hit any side of the paddle. Right now, I am only able to detect a ball and paddle collision, but I'm not sure how to figure out which side(left, top, right, or bottom) the ball hit. I like the midpoint idea, but I cannot narrow the collision down to either top/bottom or left/right. I guess if I'm able to achieve that, then I can use the midpoint idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195888/discussion-between-xcoder-and-fogmeister).